# How does the latest ANTLR4 resolve the "dangling else" ambiguity?

Tags: antlr4, compiler-theory, ambiguous-grammar, dangling-else

I am using `antlr 'org.antlr:antlr4:4.9.2'` and come across the "dangling else" ambiguity problem; see the following grammar `IfStat.g4`.

```
// file: IfStat.g4
grammar IfStat;

stat : 'if' expr 'then' stat
     | 'if' expr 'then' stat 'else' stat
     | expr
     ;

expr : ID ;

ID : LETTER (LETTER | [0-9])* ;
fragment LETTER : [a-zA-Z] ;

WS  : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

I tested this grammar against the input `"if a then if b then c else d"`. It is parsed as `"if a then (if b then c else d)" as expected. How does ANTLR4 resolve this ambiguity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR will choose the first possible (successful) path it is able to make.

You can enable ANTLR to report such ambiguities in your grammar. Check this Q&A for that: [Ambiguity in grammar not reported by ANTLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69885451/ambiguity-in-grammar-not-reported-by-antlr)